# DP approach for minimum number of characters that should be added to make a string palindrome?

Tags: c++, algorithm

> Find the minimum number of characters needed to make `S` a palindrome.For instance, if `S = "fft"`, the string should be changed to the string `"tfft"`, adding only 1 character.

Now, I used the dp approach for solving this problem which is as follows:

> Let the given input string be `S[1.....L]`. Then for any substring `S[i....j]` of the input string, we can find the minimum insertions as:
>
> - `min_insertions(S[i+1 ...... j-1])`                                    `[if S[i] is equal to S[j]]`
> - `min(min_insertions(S[i+1......j]), min_insertions(S[i....j-1])) + 1`

I coded this as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int dp[100][100];
int main (void)
{
    int n,i,j;
    char arr[100];
    cin>>arr;
    n = strlen(arr);
    //cout<<"You entered the string as "<<arr<<"\n";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        dp[i][0] = 0;  
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                dp[i][j] = dp[i+1][j-1];
            else 
                dp[i][j] = min(dp[i+1][j],dp[i][j-1])+1;
        }
    //  cout<<dp[0][n-1];
    }
    cout<<dp[0][n-1]<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

However, this gives a wrong value. Why is it happening? For example, if I enter the string as `abc`, it outputs `1`. What's wrong with this? Is there anything wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 0):

You are not filling your array dp in the right order. For instance dp[0][2] will ask for dp[1][2] which has not been computed yet.

So the logic should be to have an assigning loop of the form :

```
for (int i = 0; i <n; i++) {
    for (int h = 0; h < n-i; h++) {
        dp[i][i+h] = .. // your part
    }
}
```

You also need to be more careful about the case where `h = 0` above, where you don't want to call `dp[i+1][i]` or `dp[i][i-1]`, and `h=1, arr[i]=arr[i+1]` where you don't want `dp[i+1][i]` getting called.